# qTip2 - position of tooltip

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, tooltip, qtip2

I have no idea how can I set the proper position of my tooltips. My objects have tooltips with html structure and they are on the edges of the screen so I cannot see most of them. I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h49Loejs/2/). There are only 4 objects with tooltips but in my projects I have a lot of them.

```
$('.qtip-show').qtip({
    position: {
        target: 'mouse',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look here at the options:
http://qtip2.com/options

After playing around with the options for a while it works.

```
$('.qtip-show').each(function() { // Grab all elements with a title attribute,and set "this"
    $(this).qtip({ // 
        position: {
        my: 'top left',  // Position my top left...
        at: 'bottom left', // at the bottom right of...
        target: $(this) // my target
    }
    });
});
```

Full code here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZvomK

Bests,
George

Comment: Thank you very much, but look, when you change (for example) "while( i < 1 )" to "while( i < 10 ) " you will see that buttons on the right side are behind.

Comment: This is a limitation of the library you are using and there is nothing I can do about it. Try contacting the developer directly and see if he/she has a solution. Good luck :)